# How to detect screen mirroring in android when my mobile screen is shared using teams presentation?

Tags: android, kotlin, screenshot, android-security, android-displaymanager

For enhanced security of My Android App, I need to detect the screen mirrioring. I have implemented this below source code:

```kotlin
var display : DisplayManager = getSystemService(DISPLAY_SERVICE) as DisplayManager

var presentationdisplay= display.getDisplays(DISPLAY_CATEGORY_PRESENTATION).size

Toast.makeText(this, "disp size "+presentationdisplay, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

if(presentationdisplay>0) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "your Mobile screen is shared by other app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

The code is able to detect Screen Casting and the screen share of GoogleMeet, TeamViewer.
But it is not detecting the MicrosoftTeams and Zoom screen Sharing. I have found that MicrosoftTeams and Zoom are using `FLAG_PRIVATE` and `FLAG_PRESENTATION` whereas GoogleMeet, TeamViewer are using only `FLAG_PRESENTATION`. I assume that they are securing their virtualdisplay as private using `FLAG_PRIVATE`. Is there any way to detect Screen Mirroring with `FLAG_PRIVATE`?

Comment: Did you find solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

use this library flutter_windowmanager: ^0.2.0

to avoid and detect screen share `FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON`

for [more details](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_windowmanager)

Comment: i need to detect. I dont want to use FLAG_SECURE. anyways thanks sir.